# How to pass Authorization token from ReactJS to NodeJS request

Tags: node.js, reactjs, rest, express

I'm try to pass the 'token_mailchimp' from axios get request to nodejs request get

For the moment i pass the auth token from a variable directly in app.js in my node/express project.

app.js in node/express project

```
app.get('/mailchimp/campaigns', checkAuth, function (req, res) {
    request
        .get('https://' + mailchimpInstance + '.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/campaigns')
        .set('Content-Type', 'application/json;charset=utf-8')
        .set('Authorization', 'Basic '+token_mailchimp)
        .end((err, result) => {
            if (err) {
                res.status(500).json(err);
            } else {
                res.json(result.body);
            }
        });
});
```

axios get request in ReactJS project

```
.get('http://localhost:8081/mailchimp/campaigns',
                { headers: {"Authorization" : `Bearer `+jwt_token} })
            .then(({ data })=> {
                this.setState({
                    campaigns: data.campaigns
                });
            })
            .catch((err)=> {})
```

How can i pass from axios request the auth token for the request `/mailchimp/campaigns`?

Comment: You can send it as another header, like `{ headers: {"Authorization" : Bearer+jwt_token, 'X-TOKEN': 'yourTokenHere'} }` and then get it in nodejs with req.headers['x-token'] (https://flaviocopes.com/express-headers/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can send a new custom header like `x-api-token`

```
{ headers: {"Authorization" : Bearer+jwt_token, "x-api-token" : "your_token"} }
```

Then in the `app.js`, access the headers from the request,

```
const {headers} = req;
```

Then use that in your API request

```
.set('Authorization',`Basic ${headers["x-api-token"]}`)
```

Note: If you are using `cors` plugin then make sure it's allowing that header to pass.
You can add header `x-api-token` manually in cors configuration if needed.

Comment: i try but i recive this error: ````message: "Cannot read property 'x-api-token' of undefined"````

Comment: i recive ````authorization: "Basic undefined"````

Comment: can you try console log headers in your api code and add in question